# check if string is in array using "in"

Tags: javascript

Does this not work? I thought that this was valid, but it isn't working.

```
var items = ["image", "text"];
console.log(this.type)
if(this.type in items){
    console.log("here")
}
```

`console.log(this.type)` displays `image`, but `here` is never displayed.

Am I doing something wrong, or am I thinking of the wrong language?

Comment: You must specify index number not value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`in` checks among the property names of the object.

Here, what you need is [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if (~items.indexOf(this.type)){
```

Note: this is a short version for

```
if (items.indexOf(this.type)!==-1){
```

using the [bitwise not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7E_(Bitwise_NOT)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```js
var items = ["image", "text"];
var item = "image";
if (items.indexOf(item) > -1) {
  console.log("here");
}
```

[Array.indexOf() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 0):

The "in" keyword in JavaScript only works for keys and properties of objects. The way I would do this:

```
if (items.indexOf(this.type) !== -1)
```

This will return the index of the type you're looking for or -1 if it's not there. If it's not equal to -1, then it's there.